# Print multiple variables within using a single print func (SWIFT)

Tags: swift

I have an array containing different string values. I want to print each index on a new line with just one print func.

Thank you.

Comment: write a for loop to append the string to a mutable string variable and use \n ? `var stringToPrint = "" 
for s in array { 
    stringToPrint.append("\n")  
    stringToPrint.append("\(s)") 
} 
print(stringToPrint)`

Comment: nooo........... don't do that @MihribanMinaz  `print(array.joinWithSeparator("\n"))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `joined` Array function:

```
var newLine = "\n"
var arr = ["one", "two", "three"]
var joinedArr = arr.joined(separator: newLine)
print(joinedArr)
```

Output:

> one
>
> two
>
> three

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this obvious?

```
let stringArr = someStuff
for item in stringArr {
    print(item) // See? Only one print function here!
}
```

Okay, I'll stop messing around. I know you want `print` *to be called only once*, right?

While you can use the method shown by KlimczakM, you can also try a more functional approach:

```
print(stringArr.reduce("") {"\($0)\($1)\n"})
```

Well... I'm kind of code golfing...

A more readable approach:

```
let result = stringArr.reduce("") {
    $0 + $1 + "\n"
}
print(result)
```

Comment: First approach, as you made clear, calls `print` a lot.  Second approach ends up with an extra `"\n"` trailing at the end.